# H-99 Problems: #26 Can't Understand The Solution

Tags: haskell

I am currently working through H-99 Questions after reading Learn You a Haskell. So far I felt like I had a pretty good grasp of the concepts, and I didn't have too much trouble solving or understanding the previous problems. However, this one stumped me and I don't understand the solution.

**The problem is:**

Generate the combinations of K distinct objects chosen from the N elements of a list

In how many ways can a committee of 3 be chosen from a group of 12 people? We all know that there are C(12,3) = 220 possibilities (C(N,K) denotes the well-known binomial coefficients). For pure mathematicians, this result may be great. But we want to really generate all the possibilities in a list.

**The solution provided:**

```
import Data.List    

combinations :: Int -> [a] -> [[a]]
combinations 0 _  = [ [] ]
combinations n xs = [ y:ys | y:xs' <- tails xs, ys <- combinations (n-1) xs']
```

The main point of confusion for me is the y variable. according to how tails works it should be getting assigned the entire list at the beginning and then that list will be preppend to ys after it is generate. However, when the function run it return a list of lists no longer than the n value passed in. Could someone please help me understand exactly how this works?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Variable `y` is not bound to the whole `xs` list. For instance, assume `xs=[1,2,3]`. Then:

```
y:xs' is matched against [1,2,3]  ==> y=1 , xs'=[2,3]
y:xs' is matched against [2,3]    ==> y=2 , xs'=[3]
y:xs' is matched against [3]      ==> y=3 , xs'=[]
y:xs' is matched against []       ==> pattern match failure
```

Note that `y` is an integer above, while `xs'` is a list of integers.

---

The Haskell code can be read a a non-deterministic algorithm, as follows. To generate a combination of `n` elements from `xs`, get any tail of `xs` (i.e., drop any number of elements from the beginning). If the tail is empty, ignore it. Otherwise, let the tail be `y:xs'`, where `y` is the first element of the tail and `xs'` the remaining (possibly empty) part. Take `y` and add it to the combination we are generating (as the first element). Then recursively choose other `n-1` arguments from the `xs'` remaining part, and add those to the combination as well. When `n` drops to zero, we know there is only one combination, namely the empty combination `[]`, so take that.

Comment: Right. and if you did tails of [1,2,3] you would get [[1,2,3], [2,3], [3], []] which would mean that the first y would be the whole xs list of [1,2,3].

Comment: @acher No, `y:xs'` is `[1,2,3]`. Variable `y` is only `1` in that case.

Comment: Then why is tails required `tails xs` required? If your last comment is correct then couldn't you get the same answer by just doing `y:xs' <- xs`

Comment: @acher `y:xs' <- xs` would be a type error, since `xs` is a list of integers, and `y:xs'` is a list, hence not an integer. When extracting values from a list using the generator `z <- expression` the `expression` must have type "list of `a`" and `z` has type `a`. In the `combinations` example, you are extracting a list of integers from the list of lists of integers resulting from `tails xs`. Variable `y` is just the first element of the list of integers which as been extracted.

Comment: I am feeling really slow right now and like I am missing something really simple. I had tried running this in ghc `[y | y:xs <- tails[1,2,3]]` and it produced [1,2,3] and this is where my confusion started. because this is what y would be in the case above. (I really appreciate you taking the time to work through this with me!)

Comment: @acher That is building the list of all the `y` such that `y` is the head of some tail of `[1,2,3]`. `y` is first bound to `1`, then to `2`, then to `3`. All these values form `[1,2,3]` but `y` is never bound to that. Try evaluating `[ "y is "++show y++" and x is "++show x | y<-[1,2,3] , x<-[10,20,30] ]` for a less confusing example.

Comment: I think that you are using `tail` and not `tails` for your explanation, and that is why we are on different pages. I had to import tails from Data.List and it produces a list of lists such as this [[1,2,3], [2,3], [3], []].

Comment: I am really sorry for being so difficult on this one. I think I finally get how the function actually works. the `<-` operator grabs the first value from the list provided by tails `[[1,2,3],[2,3],[3],[]]` which is `[1,2,3]` then y goes against that list so you get `y = 1` in the first iteration. Thank you so much for sticking with me and your explanation did help!

Answer (score 0):

`y` is not appended to `ys`. That would involve the `(++) :: [a] -> [a] -> [a]` operator.

For that matter the types would not match if you tried to append `y` and `ys`. `y` has type `a`, while `ys` has type `[a]`.

Rather, `y` is consed to `ys` using `(:) :: a -> [a] -> [a]` (the cons operator).

The length of the returned list is equal to `n` because `combinations` recurses from `n` to `0` so it will produce exactly `n` inner lists.

Comment: Thank you, you are right. Sorry I don't get to talk Haskell a lot and I am new to it. I actually fixed this point in my original post. However my question remains regarding the y being set to the value of tails. Please see my comment on @chi response.